# Why doesn't Typescript error generic union type?

Tags: typescript, generics, interface, extends

```
interface Foo<T extends 'fo' | 'foo'> {
  bla: T extends 'whyNoError?' ? string : number;
}
```

Expected behaviour: See something like:

> 'whyNoError' value will never happen

Actual: no errors.

Since I specify that T extends either 'fo' or 'foo', why doesn't Typescript identify 'whyNoError' value as never or always false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#conditional-types) don't work that way, I guess?  It's an interesting suggestion to have an "unreachable code" error on the `string` part of that conditional type, but I can't imagine anyone would care much about implementing it.

Technically and pedantically, I could point out that `T` might be the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types) `'fo' & 'whyNoError?'` which, although it is an absurd type that ultimately reduces to `never`, does lead the compiler down a path you might find surprising:

```
interface Foo<T extends 'fo' | 'foo'> {
  bla: T extends 'whyNoError?' ? string : number;
}
declare const foo: Foo<'fo' & 'whyNoError?'>;
const str = foo.bla; // string !!
```

That's not a very satisfying answer because probably nobody wants to support such goofy intersections, but the takeaway should be that it's not trivial to implement what you're asking about without worrying about such edge cases.

Hope that helps; good luck!